# Toggle class of first element of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might me simple but I stuck up here !

Code :

```
<a href="#" class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
    <h6>Heading</h6>
</a>
```

On click, I want to change fa-arrow-down class to fa-arrow-up. I tried many possibilities but didn't found solution. Please help guys...

One of the methods I was trying is...

```
$('.icon').click(function () {
    if ($(this).children(':first').hasClass('fa-arrow-down')) {
        $(this).children(':first').removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-up')
    }
})
```

`console.log($(this).children())` outputs :

```
[i.fa.fa-angle-down, h6, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: a.icon]
0:i.fa.fa-angle-down
1:h6
```

Thanks

Comment: Your output says "fa-angle-down", but your code says "fa-arrow-down", so something you typed either in your code or stackoverflow is wrong.

Comment: It just works for me, unless you want it to toggle on every click

Comment: Bek, thanks ! I did typo error... Result of late night working in IT.. !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using **[`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** method like following.

```
$('.icon').click(function () {
    $(this).children(':first').toggleClass('fa-arrow-up fa-arrow-down')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
   $('.icon').click(function () {

    var hasClass = $('.icon:first-child').hasClass('fa-arrow-down');

    if (hasClass) {
        $('.icon:first-child').removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-up');
    } else {
        $('.icon:first-child').removeClass('fa-arrow-up').addClass('fa-arrow-down');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('.icon').click(function () {
 if ($(".icon > i").hasClass('fa-arrow-down')) {
       $(".icon > i").removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-up')
    }
})
```